# Dropbox icon missing in Gnome Panel

Tags: 15.04, icons, gnome-panel, dropbox

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04, Gnome Panel(gnome-session-flashback) and Dropbox. Dropbox icon is missing in the top panel. However, it is displayed corectly when I run Unity. I tried stop and start Dropbox, reinstall it but it is not working.

Update: It seems there are more broken things for me than working, so I am going to install 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Try run  `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`

Comment: I tried that before posting and it was already installed.

Answer (score 4):

`libappindicator1` may be the answer but in many cases it isn't.

The following has been submitted to www.dropbox.com as a bug but linux users don't appear to be a high priority.

---

In `dropbox`'s preferences, if you check `Start Dropbox on system startup`, the daemon will start and `dropbox` will be working in the background, but the icon will not appear.  This is apparently because the `dropbox` autostart config file `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` insists on setting a startup delay of zero but displaying the icon requires some other process to be running already... and in many cases it is not, especially when a number of other startup applications are starting up / running.

In Ubuntu's System Settings/Startup Applications, if you set the startup delay  for `dropbox` to 10 seconds or more, the process works properly and the icon appears... once. Then `dropbox` resets its startup file `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` back to a delay of zero and the problem returns.

Workaround: uncheck the `dropbox`'s preference `Start Dropbox on system startup`, write a short script that starts `dropbox`, add the script to Startup Applications and set the delay to 10 seconds or more as needed by the Ubuntu distro and by other startup settings.

Permanent fix: `dropbox` should stop rewriting the delay in the autostart file `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` or make the delay a preference.

Sample script:

```bsh
 #!/bin/bash
 dropbox stop  #because the actual daemon usually IS running
 dropbox start
 exit
```

Save it as something like `fix-dropbox-icon.sh`. Remember to make it executable in the permissions.__

Unrelated point of interest. After doing this I reviewed my Startup Applications list and changed everything that I don't consider immediately vital for a startup delay of 30 seconds or more. Now my Ubuntu startup is MUCH faster. Of course I have a lot of stuff there. Your results may differ.